# Does Android LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER provides fine accuracy location?

Tags: android, geolocation

I'm trying to receive background location update from 3rd party apps through

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_SHORT, MIN_DISTANCE, mLocationListener);
```

But it turns out that the PASSIVE_PROVIDER only gives location updates from NETWORK_PROVIDER. Is there a way to also receive updates from GPS_PROVIDER or it is not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Is there a way to also receive updates from GPS_PROVIDER or it is not supported?
```

To get the position from GPS_Provider you have to use this snippet :

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 500.0f, this);
```

where lm is your `LocationManager`. Don't forget to set uses-permission

PS: you can use both Network_Provider and GPS_Provider

Comment: Thanks Hamaza, I know that I can get GPS location from GPS_PROVIDER. I'm just curious whether I can get it from PASSIVE_PROVIDER as well

Comment: @SteveFan `PASSIVE_PROVIDER`gets location from both provider. here's a definition : http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=1375

Comment: The link is dead @SteveFan

Answer (score 3):

PASSIVE_PROVIDER means if other application fires the location search, our application will also given the location info.